# How to provide values in array query parameter in Swagger UI

Tags: rest, swagger, postman, swagger-ui, query-string

I have implemented a **swagger** with an endpoint which has an **array query parameter type**:

```
- name: "exactType"
  in: "query"
  description: "Exact types of the Refund Point"
  required: false
  type: "array"
  items:
    type: "string"
```

Which looks like this in **swagger ui**:

[image: array query parameter in swagger ui]

And I don't know how to provide values here correctly to the text area.

I can do a successful call with postman if I define the types like this:

```
GET .../myproject?types=type1&types=type2&types=type3
```

In this case the array function works fine in the backend. But I cannot make a successful call with multiple values using Swagger UI.

I have tried with linebrake, comma in the text area, but non of them worked.
How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Add `collectionFormat: multi` to your parameter, and enter the values one per line in Swagger UI. See the ^^ linked question for more information.

Comment: I could not find that solution, thanks for the link!